# Centering Image on Uploaded Image in PHP

Tags: php, image, gd

I have users uploading always-square images (of variable dimensions, but always square), and I would like to overlay my own image (also, as it was, a square and of fixed dimensions) in the middle of the square image, regardless of the size.

I know I could use GD and play with the dimensions, but is there an way to auto-center it with fewer lines of code?

I don't need anything fancy, just an image put into the center of another image.

Comment: Fewer than what? Also are you intending on rescaling any of the two graphics in question? Do you need alpha channels/opacity?

Comment: Well, right now I'm just cutting the dimensions of the big image in half, adding half of the pixels in my image, at inserting at that position. Nothing fancy, otherwise, required.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much how it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused whether you're asking how to do this in GD, or an alternative to GD. If you wanted to use the GD library, you could use the `imagecopy()` function and attempt something like the following:

```
<?php
$uploaded = imagecreatefrompng("../image.png"); //user uploaded
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng("../logo.png"); //watermark or logo

$x = imagesx($uploaded) / 2 - imagesx($watermark) / 2;
$y = imagesy($uploaded) / 2 - imagesy($watermark) / 2;

imagecopy($uploaded, $watermark, $x, $y, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($uploaded);

imagedestroy($uploaded);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Otherwise, could you be a bit more specific on what you want? I mean, you could do it with different libraries like ImageMagick, but there aren't necessarily *better* ways to do it.

Comment: That was basically my question, is there a **better** way to do it than GD with something similar to what you proposed in your answer (dividing by two, and using that as the coordinates). I do appreciate the answer.

Comment: Not really... Remember you also don't need to simply reference a php script every time you want to link to that image, you can save the content generated by the script and override the previous image so that the only accessible image is that.

Comment: Well that's the plan, but I want to see if there is a better way than just cutting the dimensions in half on both images before saving.

Comment: Why **would** there be a better way? *This* is the better way, anything else that may seem better simply duplicates the above function. Think about it - how do you find the center of an image? It's a very straightforward function...

Comment: I was just seeing if there was something like a `centerImage()` function to some library I hadn't seen. I do appreciate your response, really.

Comment: You'll find PHP has a lot of core functionality to do most jobs, then user defined functions are created to simplify or add value to the existing function set. There has to be a line drawn as to where the reach of the bundled functionality ends.