# center text in image

Tags: php, gd

So I have an image, and I am writing text and a color box onto the image. It works but it's being added to the image in the top right corner, but I need it in the center of the image. I tried changing the x and y variables, but it only moves the text and not the white box.

**Here is code**

```
$image_filepath = './kenshin.jpg';
saveImageWithText("Welcome to Eureka!", $color, $image_filepath);

function saveImageWithText($text, $color, $source_file) { 

  $public_file_path = '.';

  // Copy and resample the imag
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source_file);
  $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_file);
  imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height); 

  // Prepare font size and colors
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);
  $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255);
  $font = $public_file_path . '/arial.ttf';
  $font_size = 12; 

  // Set the offset x and y for the text position
  $offset_x = 0;
  $offset_y = 20;

  // Get the size of the text area
  $dims = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $text);
  $text_width = $dims[4] - $dims[6] + $offset_x;
  $text_height = $dims[3] - $dims[5] + $offset_y;

  // Add text background
  imagefilledrectangle($image_p, 0, 0, $text_width, $text_height, $bg_color);

  // Add text
  imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, $offset_x, $offset_y, $text_color, $font, $text);

  // Save the picture
  imagejpeg($image_p, $public_file_path . '/output.jpg', 100); 

  // Clear
  imagedestroy($image); 
  imagedestroy($image_p); 
};
```

**Here is output**

[image]

Comment: same basic idea as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310464/centering-image-on-uploaded-image-in-php

Comment: script that i give you able to change location of text

Comment: @mohammad mohsenipur how do i change the background color for the text on your example?

Comment: Can you show what specifically you changed in your code that caused it to change the text but not the white box?

Comment: @Martin Atkins I change the values for  `$offset_x = 0; $offset_y = 20;` and it centered the text but the white box was still in the top left corner

Comment: Did you try changing the `imagefilledrectangle` call to use the `$offset_x` and `$offset_y` variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will help you…

```
  <?php
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg("girl-hugging-the-globe.jpg"); // image.jpg is the image on which we are going to write text ,you can replace this iamge name with your
    if(!$img) die("Unabe to load image");
    $red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
    $green = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 255, 0);
    $width = 600;// it will store width of image 
    $height = 100; //it will store height of image
    $fontsize = 6; // size of font
    $text = "Block Prints Online"; // Define the text
    $pos = ( $width - imagefontwidth($fontsize)*STRLEN($text) );// calculate the left position of the text:
    imagestring($img, $fontsize, 200, 150, $text, $red);
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($img);//it will output a jpeg image
    imagedestroy($img);//it will destroy $img*/
    ?>
```

Comment: can you test it with this image because it only shows red text with no background color http://i49.tinypic.com/2ufptfn.jpg